# SSRS 2016: Default Year Parameter Is Not Passed to SSRS Email Subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using an expression to calculate a default value for the parameter, Year, in SSRS 2016

```
=DatePart("YYYY", DateAdd("YYYY", -1, Today()))
```

When I run a report on a one-off basis, the parameter populates. However, when I try to configure an email subscription and choose to have the parameter populated by using the Default Value, I am presented with an error that reads

> An error has occurred.
>   This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'Year'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value.

Is my expression not configured correctly? It seems unlikely as the report performs as expected when run manually.

Comment: You may want to check the default for the parameters in the server. They don't get updated after the initial deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tony D's comment put me on the path to the answer. **The report had to be deleted from and re-added to the server to clear the cache.** After doing this, the parameter filled as expected. I found this suggestion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a548d65-35d0-4a3e-8b64-3b7b655c76ee/ssrs-2008-report-parameter-default-value-doesnt-work-when-deployed?forum=sqlreportingservices). Thank you, Tony!

Comment: No worries mate